# Zend Framework 1x append js script to head

Tags: javascript, php, zend-framework

just like in topic I try to load JS file to head. In my admin.phtml layout file I have somthing like that:

```
<?php
    $this->headScript()->prependScript('var baseUrl = \'' . $this->baseUrl() . '\';');
    echo $this->headScript();
?>
```

and when I try to add script in view file by:

```
<?php
$this->headScript()
     ->appendFile($this->baseUrl() . '/pub/js/multiSelect.js', 'text/javascript', array());
?>
```

but this file isn't added. Only works when I add script below in controler or in admin.phtml layout file before echo $this->headScript(). There is the way to add scripts in view files?
Regards

Comment: This should work, and your code looks okay so we'll need a bit more info about the code you're using and the exact output

Comment: I think I found what is wrong. The problem is because this content of action is loaded by ajax and have disabled layout. There is the way to append file in head? I need this in form helper class and only should load when this helper is run in view.